# Desempaquetar paquete de datos hexadecimales en python

Tags: python

Tengo un aparato que me un valor hexadecimal, el cual representa un conjunto de valores decimales codificados entre uno o más bytes según el tamaño de este.

Lo que estoy intentando es acceder a posiciones de bytes concretos para así poder traducirlas a decimal y en consecuencia obtener el valor que necesito.

`000100000001f8c65400fefe3195000001230000000000000000000000000000000000000000642b00090700000000001e`

Yo en `python` cuando quiero traducir un valor de hexadecimal a decimal hago

```
print(int(valor_hex,16))
```

Y ya obtengo el valor que quiero. La cosa, es que como he dicho antes, este gran valor hexadecimal es el conjunto de varios bytes unidos con diferentes valores decimales individuales. ¿Como hago para acceder a un (o unos) bytes concretos para conocer su valor?

Por ejemplo, me gustaría acceder al byte 34 que se que será un valor numérico entre 0 y 100 y a los bytes 18 hasta 21, que representarán otro valor de tamaño enorme y que por ello necesita 4 bytes (lo único que sé es que empieza por 39).

La cosa está en que si yo hago,

```
a = valor_hex[18:22] # 18 to 21
print(a)
print(int(a,16))
```

Ni de cerca da lo que quiero, ¿como se debería hacer para acceder al byte deseado?

**EDIT**

Si este es el valor hexadecimal a trabajar,

```
v_hex = 000100000001f8c65400fefe3195000001230000000000000000000000000000000000000000642b00090700000000001e
```

Y yo lo convierto en su totalidad (cosa que supongo no es correcto)

```
print(int(v_hex,16))
```

Obtengo lo siguiente

```
153914086775326342143664486282692693880080977757509806775956245674142536051238079779640236240803190331364310253598
```

Si empezamos la cuenta en un 1, vemos que a partir de la tercera posición hay un 39140867753. Yo se que esto es mi valor de latitud (39.140867753) y que el siguiente valor a este 2634214366 es mi longitud (2.634214366) pues yo se donde pusieron el sensor GPS para hacer las pruebas. ¿Como ese 39.etc equivale a byte 18 a 21? ¿O son casualidad esos valores y me están liando?

*Yo vivo en Mallorca y esos valores aunque no son exactos dan muy cerca ¿es casualidad?*

¡¡Gracias!!

Comment: Tiene que ser casualidad que aparezca algo que se parece a tu latitud/longitud como parte del super-número. No hay relación alguna entre ese número y los bytes que lo componían. De hecho ¿y si tu latitud o longitud fueran negativas? Creo que es necesaria una mejor especificación de lo que contiene la cadena hexadecimal. ¿Tienes la marca del sensor a ver si online se puede encontrar algo?

Answer (score 1):

Ten en cuenta que un byte en hexadecimal son dos cifras. Por ejemplo, un byte de valor 255 en hexadecimal sería "FF". En tu pregunta parece que confundes bytes con cifras hexadecimales.

Planteas dos ejemplos de qué querrías hacer:

#### Acceder a un byte individual

Pones por ejemplo el byte 34 que tendría un valor numérico entre 0 y 100. Esto es bastante directo, ya que se trata de tomar dos cifras de tu cadena hexadecimal; las dos cifras comprendidas entre la posición n*2 y (n+1)*2 (siendo `n` el byte que quieres acceder).

```
def valor_byte(secuencia_hex, n):
   return int(secuencia_hex[n*2:(n+1)*s], 16)
```

El resultado aplicándolo a tu ejempo sale 0.

#### Acceder a un dato de varios bytes

Parece que a priori el esquema sería el mismo, pero en vez de tomar 2 cifras tomaríamos 4, 8... o las que se necesiten según el tamaño en bytes del dato que quieres extraer. Así que la siguiente función debería servir:

```
def valor_entero(secuencia_hex, n, tamaño):
    return int(secuencia_hex[n*2:(n+tamaño)*2], 16)
```

Si lo aplicamos a tu cadena, con `n=18, tamaño=4` sale también 0.

#### Caso general

De hecho, esta misma función sirve para sacar bytes individuales si haces `tamaño=1`, por lo que podríamos juntar todo y tener:

```
def valor_entero(secuencia_hex, n, tamaño=1):
    return int(secuencia_hex[n*2:(n+tamaño)*2], 16)

h = "000100000001f8c65400fefe3195000001230000000000000000000000000000000000000000642b00090700000000001e"

print(valor_entero(h, 34))     # Acceso al byte 34: Sale 0
print(valor_entero(h, 18, 4))  # Acceso al entero de 32 bits en 18. Sale 0
```

Estos resultados no sé si son lo que esperas o no. Creo que en tu pregunta estás confundiendo "bytes" con "dígitos hexadecimales". Cuando dices que necesitas el byte 34 ¿quieres decir el byte que comienza en la posición 34 de tu cadena? Ese no sería el byte 34 sino el 17 ya que cada byte ocupa dos caracteres. Lo mismo cabe preguntarse sobre el "byte 18" ¿será en realidad el 9? Y cuando dices que ocupa 4 bytes ¿quieres decir 4 dígitos hexadecimales? Porque eso serían 2 bytes...

Para que compares a ver si alguno de estos sale lo que buscas, te pongo más ejemplos:

```
print(valor_entero(h, 17))     # Byte en posición 17: sale 35
print(valor_entero(h, 9, 4))   # Entero de 32 bits que comienza en byte 9: 16711217
print(valor_entero(h, 9, 2))   # Entero de 16 bits que comienza en byte 9: 254
```

Y si ninguno de estos valores es lo que esperabas, tal vez sea un problema de *endianity* (los bytes correspondientes a datos de 16 o 32 bits están almacenados en orden inverso en la cadena). Escribe un comentario si así fuera para proponer una solución.

## Usando `struct.unpack()`

En realidad con lo anterior estamos "reinventando la rueda", pues Python ya tiene en su módulo `struct` funciones para tratar precisamente con este problema, es decir, el problema de tener una secuencia de bytes en una variable, que en realidad representa varios valores binarios de diferentes tamaños.

Para usar esta funcionalidad, lo primero es tener los bytes como bytes realmente y no como una cadena hexadecimal. Esto es sencillo:

```
>>> h = "000100000001f8c65400fefe3195000001230000000000000000000000000000000000000000642b00090700000000001e"
>>> data = bytes.fromhex(h)
```

Ahora `data` es una cadena de bytes. Por ejemplo `data[17]` te da acceso al byte 17 directamente:

```
>>> data[17]
35
```

Pero cuando quieres sacar más de un byte, como por ejemplo los 4 bytes que hay a partir de `data[9]`, el resultado ya no es un entero, sino una sub-cadena de bytes:

```
>>> data[9:13]
b'\x00\xfe\xfe1'
```

Y es que Python no puede convertir una secuencia de bytes en un entero directamente pues el resultado depende del orden en memoria de esos bytes. En arquitecturas *little-endian* los bytes se guardan de modo que el primero es el menos significativo, pero en las *big-endian* el primero es el más significativo. Sin saber la endianity de la máquina que generó esos datos, no podemos saber cómo convertirlos.

El paquete `struct` tiene la función `struct.unpack()` que recibe dos parámetros:

- El primero es una cadena de formato especial que especifica qué tipos de datos tenemos en los bytes.
- El segundo es la cadena de bytes de la que queremos extraer la información

La cadena de formato comienza por un carácter que puede ser `>` o `<` y especifica la *endianity* con que los datos están almacenados en la cadena de bytes (`<` para little endian, `>` para big endian). El carácter siguiente indica el tamaño en bytes del dato y su tipo: `H` para un dato (sin signo) de tipo *short*, es decir, 16 bits o 2 bytes. `L` para un dato (sin signo) de tipo *long*, es decir, 32 bits o 4 bytes. Las correspondientes versiones con signo son `h` y  `l`. Hay bastantes más posibilidades, puedes verlas todas [en la documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-strings).

El resultado de `unpack()` es una tupla con todos los valores que se han extraido de acuerdo con el formato especificado (el formato podría especificar más de un valor, por ejemplo `">h>h" indica que hay dos enteros cortos en big-endian). En nuestros ejempos la tupla resultante tendrá un solo valor, pues extraemos un solo dato.

Veamos varios ejemplos de cómo interpretar lo que hay tras el byte 9:

```
>>> import struct

# Es un entero corto, sin signo, en little-endian:
>>> struct.unpack("<H", data[9:11])
(65024,)

# Es un entero corto, sin signo, en big-endian:
>>> struct.unpack(">H", data[9:11])
(254,)


# Es un entero largo, sin signo, en little-endian:
>>> struct.unpack("<L", data[9:13])
(838794752,)

# Es un entero largo, sin signo, en big-endian:
>>> struct.unpack(">L", data[9:13])
(16711217,)
```

Si sabes el significado de todos los bytes de tu cadena de datos, puedes extraerlos con un solo `unpack()`, especificando el formato de cada dato en la cadena de formato y recibiendo como resultado una tupla con todos los datos extraidos.

Comment: Mil gracias por la de conocimientos aportados en un solo post. Pero ninguno de los valores que salen son los deseados. El problema que tengo es que se me ha dado poca información sobre los datos. Básicamente me han dado ese valor gigante hexadecimal que viene de un sensor y me han dicho que extraiga la información de ciertos bytes, por ejemplo el byte 34 se que será la batería del sensor, y el byte 18 a 21 (4 bytes) tiene la latitud, los 4 siguientes longitud...

Comment: Probé a ir de izquierda a derecha o derecha izquierda por temas de LSB o MSB pero nada. Algo que me llama la atención, es que si convierto el hexadecimal gigante, yo veo que a partir del tercer carácter aparece la latitud (un 39), pues yo se donde está el sensor y que en la 14 aparece la longitud (un 2) pero no sé como se traduce que la posición 3 equivalga a byte 18 la verdad.